# I'm getting this error while installing react js in VS code

Tags: reactjs, npm, npx

```
$ npx create-react-app my-project

Creating a new React app in D:\react\my-project.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! errno ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y: Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-02-28T07_59_07_158Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-project/ from D:\react
Done.
```

Comment: You have a problem with your network ... You can't reach the registry at `npmjs.org`

Comment: `If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'` - does this apply to you, and if so, have you done this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to create a react application using the create-react-app not that you are installing react on vscode. Maybe you may need to reframe the question.

Meanwhile, here is why you are having that error -
By running the create-react-app, you are trying to fetch and download modules, dependencies from the npm registry to your computer.

npm is failing to fetch those modules because your internet may be disconnected.

There could be a problem with your internet connection. Ensure it's working, try another one or increase npm fetch timeout.

Comment: My internet connection is pretty good and i also increased the fetch timeout but this  error appears again .

Comment: Maybe you could try using Vite for scaffolding your react app. It's very fast and makes it very easy to set up React application in seconds. run :  npm init vite  , 
and Follow the instruction to install 
cd into the folder 
npm install
npm run dev     
 Check the doc here - https://vitejs.dev/guide/#index-html-and-project-root

Answer (score 0):

1. you can try this please. I had a similar issue

   1.npm uninstall -g create-app

   2.npm uninstall crate react-app

   3.npx create-react-app (app name of your choice)